# Download or Connect csv data from FTP wiht R

Tags: r, ftp, rstudio

How Can I get csv data from ftp file protected with password by using R? For example there is ftp url

```
ftp.example.com/my_file/example.csv
```

And you your username:user123 pasword:Test123

How can I access to this datat or download whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of a sftp-server I use 'getURL' function from RCurl package

For your input, and an sfpt-server, the first call would download the file.

Maybe its similar for a regular ftp-connection(second call)?

```
# sftp
RCurl::getURL(url = "sftp://user123:Test123@example.com/my_file/example.csv")

# maybe works for a ftp connection
RCurl::getURL(url = "ftp://user123:Test123@example.com/my_file/example.csv")
```

hope it helps :)